# Can remove data in c# MVC.Net?

Tags: c#

I want to remove my selected record (eg. product id - 3) . How can I take this parameter in this id with form action and controller? And then, how to refresh this page already removed this id?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddProduct", "Product", FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-horizontal" })){<table class="table"><tr><th>Product ID</th><th>Product Name</th><th></th></tr>@{for (var j = 0; j < Model.Products.Count; j++){<tr><td>@Html.DisplayFor(pc => pc.PendingClasses[j].ProductID)</td><td>@Html.DisplayFor(pc => pc.PendingClasses[j].ProductName)</td><td>@using (Html.BeginForm("RemoveProduct", "Product", new { productid = @Model.Products[j].ProductID }, FormMethod.Post)){<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="btnRemove" value="Remove">Remove</button>}</td></tr>}}<tr><td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="btnAdd" value="Add">Add</button></td></tr></table>}
```

Comment: What kind of database scheme you have used? Please provide some code for details.

Comment: I have used MSSQL 2008 R2.

Comment: Have you every queried the database using c# ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the controler methods for CRUD already, that will remove the entry from database?

```
    // from /Controller/product.cs
    public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
    {
        Product product = db.Product.Find(id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(product);
    }

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Product product = db.Product.Find(id);
        db.Product.Remove(product);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Product");
    }
```